# Populate combo box with SQL results and ignore the extra output

Tags: sql-server, winforms, powershell, view

I have an application I made with PowerShell that obtains info from a SQL database for various controls. My 'View', will occasionally work perfectly. But if I close the application and reopen, the same thing can yield different results. I've set PS to run as admin, but again the same issue. The view should read 1971 results and look like

```
#ASP.Net Client Ugrade
C# Client Upgrade
Another Basic Project Name
```

However, while this works correctly some of the time...the output I get when it decides to not load correctly is

```
#ASP.Net Client Ugrade
1971
void Open(), void IDbConne
```

I'm not sure why it's adding property information instead of the values being requested. Also not sure why the results sometimes are right and sometimes wrong, while doing the same behavior(Just starting the program, the box is populated on load). Relevant code to how I'm selecting and populating the data:

```
[string[]]$projectsAll = ""  #I only do it this way because the sql query is actually in a method, were I return the array-and then do the foreach item in the array add to the projectview  
$query = "select Title from OversightProjectsFix where ID > 0 Order By Title"
    if ($sqlcon.State -eq 'Closed'){$sqlcon.Open()}
    $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $SqlCmd.CommandText = $query
    $SqlCmd.Connection = $sqlcon
    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
    $ds = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($ds)|out-null
    foreach ($Row in $ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    { 
        $projectsAll += "$($Row.Title)"
    }
$ProjectView.Items.Clear()
foreach ($p in $projectsAll)
{
$ProjectView.Items.Add($p)
}
```

As I mentioned before, if this same code is ran, you should always get the same results-but this one returns differently and I'm not sure why? How can I make it always work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand exactly what is wrong with this snippit of code, but I think that it may be because the DataSet is empty, and you are . i.e. I think that it isn't connecting and pulling any data.

Since the dataset is initialized with `New-Object`, if it didn't fill properly, what happens is if you try to iterating through it using quotes, instead of adding it as a straight assignment, it may cause it to unexpectedly return the data type instead of an "expected" null or empty string. You can see this when you try something like this:

```
$ds = New-Object System.Data.DataSet

#Returns Null
PS> $ds.Tables[0].Rows
PS> 

#Returns data type
PS> "$ds.Tables[0].Rows"
System.Data.DataSet.Tables[0].Rows
```

So you may have to remove the quotes i.e.:

```
$projectsAll += $Row.Title
```

You should add a check to see if the dataset has something before trying to iterate and add anything.

Also, usually by implementing the `$SqlAdapter.Fill($ds)` method opens the connection, without you needing to explicitly open the SQL connection. I wonder if your inconsistencies is due to the SQL connection opening/closing unexpectedly?

Comment: I know that using a stream reader seems to be working. I'll give your version a try as soon as I can pull the script up

Comment: And it works without adding the quotes each time. thank you!